# Forwarding Client Certifcate from Apache to Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, spring-security, x509

I am trying to pass a x509 client certificate (I have a test cert installed on my browser) from the Apache web server (SSL) to the Tomcat application.  The way I have it configured right now, the certificate is not being found (hence not forwarded) by the application's spring security.

```
DEBUG: [http-8080-1]  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.x509.X509AuthenticationFilter - No client certificate found in request.
```

The Apache server `ssl.conf` file is configured like this (I have omitted the irrelevant parts):

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ...

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 2

    ...

    # initialize the SSL headers to a blank value to avoid http header forgeries
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT ""
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY ""

    # add whatever SSL_* variables needed to pass to web application
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"

    RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Scheme https

    ProxyPass /testcert http://127.0.0.1:8080/testcert
    ProxyPassReverse /testcert http://127.0.0.1:8080/testcert

</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way to configure this in Apache where the entire certificate gets forwarded to the Tomcat server?  I know I could use `ajp` but was trying to get it done without that method.

Comment: Are you saying that what you have doesn't work - that you don't see the SSL_CLIENT_CERT header in tomcat?

Comment: @Luke I see the header, and according to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html), the `SSL_CLIENT_CERT` is a "PEM-encoded client certificate" but it isn't coming through on the Tomcat server.  Spring security says it is not receiving the certificate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're passing the certificate as a header, tomcat won't automatically be aware of it since the connection is just HTTP rather than HTTPS. Instead of getting the certifcate as a request attribute, you'll have to extract it from the header and parse it yourself.

You can override the [`getPreAuthenticationCredentials` method in `X509AuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509AuthenticationFilter.java#L25). There's some code [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509TestUtils.java#L133) which shows how to decode the certificate.

### Bean Configuration

You remove the `<x509 />` namespace element and replace it with the equivalent beans. There's an appendix in the reference manual which explains what beans an XML element creates. Your configuration should look like this:

```
<http entry-point-ref="http403">
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="x509Filter" />
</http>

<bean id="http403" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<bean id="x509Filter" class="YourExtendedX509AuthenticaitonFilter" />
```

Comment: That seems like it will get the job done.  I have re-written the method but, being not nearly as proficient with spring as you, I am unsure where to inject the bean containing the class and how I am supposed to call it.  Is it enough to declare the bean and let spring security recognize that it's there?  In addition, should I still keep the `<x509 ... />` declaration in the `<http>` section since this is a preauth?

Comment: Updated to include a configuration example.