# Uniquely identifying clients with client-side SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

In the following scenario,

```
[client]---https--->[Nginx]---http--->[app server]
```

How (and what) would I pass down to the app server to uniquely identify the certificate? That is, Nginx validates the certificate, but app server doesn't see it. I need to distinguish between users at the app server, so they can't impersonate each other.

Comment: Are you trying to tell clients with SSL from clients without SSL, or are you hoping to be able to uniquely identify every client who uses SSL, based on client-specific SSL certificates?

Comment: @MarkStosberg The latter. There are only SSL clients, the idea is to *uniquely identify each client without a password.*

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt the same technique as what's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14717185/372643) for Apache Httpd. You'd need the Nginx equivalent of something like:

```
RequestHeader set X-ClientCert ""
RequestHeader set X-ClientCert "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
```

I haven't tried, but the documentation for the [Nginx SSL module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) has a section about "Embedded Variables". More specifically:

> `$ssl_client_cert` returns the client certificate in the PEM format for an established SSL connection, with each line except the first prepended
>   with the tab character; this is intended for the use in the
>   `proxy_set_header` directive;

This looks like what you need with a reverse-proxy setting, like the one you have.

Note that it's very important to clear this header on its way in, otherwise clients could just set the headers themselves and use any certificate they like.

How you then want to check this in your application server depends on the platform you're using. In Java, for example, you could write a Filter (or a Tomcat Valve) that sets the parameter in the request from this custom HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use Nginx for SSL termination, but you want the backend servers to be able to tell with the original request was over HTTPS or HTTP.
I think something this could work:

```
server {
    ssl on;
    listen 443;

    add_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;

    proxy_pass ...
}

# If you need insecure requests as well
server {
    listen 80;

    add_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  http;

    proxy_pass ...
}
```

Then your app server can check the value of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

This is the same design pattern that Amazon Web Services uses for terminating SSL at their Elastic Load Balancers. They also set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header for backend servers to check.